# MariaDB query stuck, optimizer bug?

Tags: sql, mariadb

We are using MariaDB version 10.3.35 and have come across one of our queries running particularly slowly.

```sql
SELECT
    `facilityId`,
    COUNT(`accommodationId`) as accommodationCount
FROM `AccommodationHasCombinedFacilities`
JOIN `Facility`
ON `AccommodationHasCombinedFacilities`.`facilityId` = `Facility`.`id` AND `Facility`.`isSearchCriterion` = 1
WHERE
    `AccommodationHasCombinedFacilities`.`accommodationId` IN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT `AccommodationHasCombinedFacilities`.`accommodationId`
        FROM `AccommodationHasCombinedFacilities`
        WHERE `AccommodationHasCombinedFacilities`.`facilityId` IN (191, 29) -- These IDs can change per query
        GROUP BY `AccommodationHasCombinedFacilities`.`accommodationId`
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `AccommodationHasCombinedFacilities`.`facilityId`) = 2 -- This number equals the amount of IDs above
    )
GROUP BY `facilityId`
ORDER BY `facilityId`
```

The table `AccommodationHasCombinedFacilities` consists of two columns, combining ~18.600 accommodation IDs and ~300 facility IDs, making up a total of ~588.000 rows.

We can't figure out why this query takes incredibly long to run. Running `EXPLAIN` with this query indicates that the engine thinks the subquery is a dependant subquery:

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | Facility | ref | PRIMARY,isSearchCriterion | isSearchCriterion | 2 | const | 34 | Using where; Using index |
| 1 | PRIMARY | AccommodationHasCombinedFacilities | ref | facilityId | facilityId | 4 | Facility.id | 1272 | Using where |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | AccommodationHasCombinedFacilities | index | facilityId | accommodationId | 1022 | *NULL* | 2997 | Using where |

From our analysis we've come to the conclusion however that the subquery is independent and always provides a static result set for the IDs that are provided to it. Our solution in the end was to run the subquery first, then inject the retrieved list of accommodation IDs into the original query, which fixed the issue and made the query run as fast as we had expected it to:

```sql
SELECT
    `facilityId`,
    COUNT(`accommodationId`) as accommodationCount
FROM `AccommodationHasCombinedFacilities`
JOIN `Facility`
ON `AccommodationHasCombinedFacilities`.`facilityId` = `Facility`.`id` AND `Facility`.`isSearchCriterion` = 1
WHERE
    `AccommodationHasCombinedFacilities`.`accommodationId` IN
    (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 /* etc. for about 70 IDs */)
GROUP BY `facilityId`
ORDER BY `facilityId`
```

**Is this a bug with MariaDB's query optimizer or have we done something wrong with our original query?**

Comment: is the number of ids **AccommodationHasCombinedFacilities`.`facilityId` IN (191, 29)** always 2 ?

Comment: does just joining your subquery instead of using WHERE ... IN work?  `FROM ( your subquery ) ids JOIN AccommodationHasCombinedFacilities USING (accommodationId) JOIN Facility ...`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the performance of this query pls:

**WHERE EXISTS** is faster

(is not tested)

```
SELECT `facilityId`, COUNT(`accommodationId`) as accommodationCount
FROM `AccommodationHasCombinedFacilities` AS acf
JOIN `Facility` AS f
ON `acf`.`facilityId` = f.`id` AND f.`isSearchCriterion` = 1
WHERE EXISTS
 (SELECT a.`accommodationId` FROM `AccommodationHasCombinedFacilities` AS a 
  WHERE acf.accommodationId = a.accommodationId AND a.`facilityId` = 191)
AND EXISTS
 (SELECT a.`accommodationId` FROM `AccommodationHasCombinedFacilities` AS b 
  WHERE acf.accommodationId = b.accommodationId AND b.`facilityId` = 20)
GROUP BY `facilityId`
ORDER BY `facilityId`;
```